# Why does my UISearchBar shrink when tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

When I load my code, the UISearchBar appears normally. However, after I tap the search field, the search bar shrinks and drops vertically lower. Code:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    var searchBarController: UISearchController?
    var tableViewController: UITableViewController?
    var searchBar: UISearchBar?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = .blue

        let tableViewController = UITableViewController(style: .plain)
        let searchBarController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: tableViewController)

        self.searchBarController = searchBarController
        self.tableViewController = tableViewController

        self.searchBar = self.searchBarController?.searchBar
        self.searchBar?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 75)
        self.searchBar?.searchBarStyle = .prominent
        self.view.addSubview(self.searchBar!)

    }    
}
```

Here is a visual before and after tapping:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Remove sizetoFit() and try

Comment: @PratikPrajapati sorry meant to remove that from my code. I have removed it and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Why you’re using SearchBarCobtroller instead use UISearchBar.init()?

Comment: @PratikPrajapati I was using SearchBarController because I was going to use it later in the process to coordinate with the tableviewcontroller for the results (and any other searchBarController functionality). However, when I remove usage of SearchBarController and separately init a UISearchBar and add it to the view, the search bar no longer shrinks. Why is the SearchBarController impacting the UI like that?

Comment: This is the onle screen ? U are using UiSearchBarController?

Comment: @PratikPrajapati Yes this is the only screen. MainViewController is the root view controller of this app, and what you see above is the only code for MainViewController

Comment: Okie, i let you know what’s the issue!

Comment: @PratikPrajapati do you know why the search bar was causing the issue? Do you know how to fix the issue if I want to keep my search bar controller?

Comment: Currently I don’t know what’s causing the issue, I’ll check n let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIkit will resize the searchcontroller's view on `layoutSubviews()` which will reset your frame.

If you want to control the size of the search bar independently, I'll suggest you make `searchbar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` and/or in `viewDidLayoutSubview()` resize your searchbar with `searchbar.frame = ...`